# Reading frames from Flask Server into PyCharm

Tags: python, opencv, flask, url

> ```
> from flask import Flask, Response, request, send_file
> from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
> import socket
> import cv2 as cv2
>
> app = Flask(__name__)
>
> video_path = "videos/video.avi"
>
> @app.route('/video_feed/')
> def video_feed():
>     start_frame = int(request.args.get("start_frame"))
>     end_frame = int(request.args.get("end_frame"))
>     return Response(gen(start_frame, end_frame), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
>
> def gen(start_frame, end_frame):
>     cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
>     cap.set(1, start_frame)
>     while True:
>         success, img = cap.read()
>         current_frame = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)
>         if current_frame > end_frame:
>             break
>         imgencode = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)[1]
>         stringData = imgencode.tobytes()
>         # can also use tostring()
>         yield (b'--frame\r\n'
>                b'Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n' + stringData + b'\r\n')
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000, debug=True)
> ```
>
> So, this is the Flask server I am running. I am able to view the correct frames being yielded by the flask server at this URL: (It doesn't matter that the video playback is too fast)
>
> ```
> http://127.0.0.1:8000/video_feed/?start_frame=0&end_frame=5000
> ```
>
> But I can't seem to figure out how to use this URL into a development environment like PyCharm to be able to read the frames from this URL into a python script, for example.

```
url="http://127.0.0.1:8000/video_feed/?start_frame=4000&end_frame=5001"
while True:
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    response = resp.read()
    data = resp.split(b'\r\n\r\n', 1)[1]
    i = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.uint8)
    img = cv2.imdecode(i, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    cv2.imshow("frame", img)
    if cv2.waitKey(16) & 0xFF==ord('q'):
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

So this is what I have tried for reading the frames into PyCharm but it **only reads the first frame**. I want it to be able to ingest all of the frames from the URL. I know that there is something I am not understanding when it comes to URL's or generator functions, so any refactoring or help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Replace the `Content-Type text/plain` to `image/jpeg`. Also, you should be able to open an `VideoCapture` passing the url on the client

Comment: Yeah that is it! Thanks so much, was a real headache for me, had no idea you could input a URL to VideoCapture. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

On the Flask server side the adjustment is made to the generator function:

```
yield (b'--frame\r\n'
       b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + stringData + b'\r\n')
```

And then read into an IDE like pycharm as such:

```
import cv2

vcap = cv2.VideoCapture('http://127.0.0.1:8000/video_feed/? 
start_frame=4000&end_frame=5001')
while True:
    ret, frame = vcap.read()
    if frame is not None:
         cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
         if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
             break
    else:
         print("Frame is None")
         break
 vcap.release()
 cv2.destroyAllWindows()
 print("Video stop")
```